# How to eager load one row from `has_many` association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have these models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :agent_logins

  def active_login
    agent_logins.active.order('created_at DESC').first
  end 
end

class AgentLogin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
end
```

And I have this API controller with this serializer

```
class API::UsersController < API::APIController
  def index
     respond_with User.all
  end
end

class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :pin, :voicemail, :name, :active_login
end
```

And this, of cource, produces N+1 problem

```
User Load (7.7ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`
  AgentLogin Load (2.7ms)  SELECT `agent_logins`.* FROM `agent_logins` WHERE `agent_logins`.`user_id` = 3 AND `agent_logins`.`active` = 1 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
  AgentLogin Load (3.8ms)  SELECT `agent_logins`.* FROM `agent_logins` WHERE `agent_logins`.`user_id` = 16 AND `agent_logins`.`active` = 1 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
  AgentLogin Load (3.8ms)  SELECT `agent_logins`.* FROM `agent_logins` WHERE `agent_logins`.`user_id` = 18 AND `agent_logins`.`active` = 1 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

Is there a preferred way to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: Hi there, actually I didn't. But the answer below was edited and it could work, you can try. I will be forced to solve this later, so stay in touch - I will publish the soulution, if I will be able to find one.

Comment: It is my answer. I just wanted to know if made it work somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this quite not elegant solution.

Make a separate class called ActiveLogins

```
class User
  has_one :active_login
end

class ActiveLogins 
  belongs_to :user #=> foregin key :user_id 
end
```

Every time you create a AgentLogin you also create a identical ActiveLogin an delete all other ActiveLogins with the same :user_id

Then you can call User.all.includes(:active_login) (hopefully without N+1 issues)

Comment: Nope this doesn't work. It was the first thing I tried :). I guess it's because of that condition `agent_logins.active`.

Comment: Yes I guessed you had ;). Updated  the answer